# EE e-Commerce + MSM capabilities

Tags: expresso-store, cartthrob, multi-site-manager, localization, brilliantretail

I've got a client that needs to be able to manage product inventory / availability separately across a few MSM sites (each site is a national branch of the organization, and some products simply aren't available in some countries). They also need currency localization for each store (USD, GBP, EUR, AUD, NZD, etc), as well as store-specific billing info (eg. different PayPal accounts for each national branch).

I know it's asking a lot, but can any of the EE e-commerce solutions (CartThrob, BrilliantRetail, and Exp:resso Store - or anything else I'm unfamiliar with) handle this kind of MSM setup, even partially?

Comment: Grr... not enough rep to create a "brilliantretail" tag. Odd it doesn't exist already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not speak for BrilliantRetail as I have never used it on a MSM site but you should not have problems creating separate stores completely with different currency, payment accounts, and products with either Store or CartThrob. I would assume the same would be true for BR but I can not speak from experience.

Comment: Thanks, Justin! Those are the two I was leaning towards anyway; the core of EE's power is in the custom entry fields, and I can't bear the thought of ignoring that aspect. :)

Comment: I wanted to chime in that BR does allow for this type of separate store per MSM site and more importantly I want to clear up the misconception that custom field types are not available to BrilliantRetail products. BR does have a standard data structure for core product fields but you can add your own custom EE fields to meet any specific requirements.